# Linux/Bash Loop through 10k lines in file and replace strings using sed

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I have two files. The first file contains two columns of data, roughly 10,000 lines. The other is a huge .xml file (GB+) were certain information needs to be replaced.

Currently, I am using a while loop to read in both columns of data, then use sed to replace in the xml file. This unfortunately is taking 5+ hours to run, and am in need of a more efficient process.

File 1:

```
123456789    987654321
234567891    876543219
345678912    765432198
456789123    654321987
...
```

File 2:

```
<Tag>123456789</Tag>
...
<Tag>234567891</Tag>
```

Current Script:

```
#! /bin/bash

count=$(cat $1 | wc -l)

while read -r old new; do
        ((count-=1))
        echo -e "Old value: ${old}  -  New value: ${new}  -  Values Left: ${count}"

        sed -i "s/"$old"/"$new"/" $2
done < $1
```

`./script.sh file1.txt file2.xml`

The goal of the script is to replace $old with $new, only when it finds an exact match to the 9 character integer in between `<Tag>` and `</Tag>`.

Expected result:

```
<Tag>98654321</Tag>
...
<Tag>876543219</Tag>
```

Comment: something like `awk` will require a single pass through each file and be much, Much, MUCH faster; couple issues with current code ... 1) will replace all instances of `$old`, even if *not* between `<Tag>` and `</Tag>` ... 2) will replace all instances of `$old`, even as a substring of a larger string (eg, `old=5` will get replaced for `5`, `157`, `253545`, etc) ... please update question with clarification/details on how to match `$old`; also, recommend you update the question to provide a few more sample lines from the xml file as well as a section to show the expected results

Comment: @markp-fuso Thank you for the help, yes, you are correct, I need it to only replace the integer when it finds an exact match between the two tags. It will always be a 9 character integer between the tags as well. I have updated the post to reflect this goal as well/

Answer (score 3):

With **GNU** sed, a regex bash and process substitution:

```
sed -f <(sed -E 's#([^ \t]+)[ \t]+([^ \t]+)#s|<Tag>\1</Tag>|<Tag>\2</Tag>|g#;' file1.txt) file2.xml
```

I switched from common `s///` to `s###` and `s|||` on order to handle `/` character required in output.

```
sed -f <(
    sed -E '
      s#([^ \t]+)[ \t]+([^ \t]+)# s|<Tag>\1</Tag>|<Tag>\2</Tag>|g; #
    ' file1.txt
) file2.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

As usual, `sed` or anything else involving regular expressions is the wrong approach to take with XML documents. Here's a perl script that uses the [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) module (Install through your OS's package manager or favorite CPAN client) to efficiently handle huge documents:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

# Takes two arguments - the one of lines tags to change and what to
# change to, and the input XML document. Outputs to standard output;
# redirect to a file if needed.

my ($tag_file, $xml_file) = @ARGV;
open my $tags, "<", $tag_file or die "Unable to open $tag_file: $!\n";
my %replacements;
while (<$tags>) {
    chomp;
    my ($from, $to) = split;
    $replacements{$from} = $to;
}
close $tags;

my $xml = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        Tag => sub {
            my $id = $_->text;
            if (exists $replacements{$id}) {
                $_->set_text($replacements{$id});
            }
            $_->flush;
        }
    },
    pretty_print => 'indented' # Use 'none' instead to save space in big files
                               # that don't need to be human-readable.
    );
$xml->parsefile($xml_file);
$xml->flush;
```

Example usage:

```sh
$ cat input.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document>
  <Tag>123456789</Tag>
  <Tag>234567891</Tag>
  <Tag>345678912</Tag>
  <OtherTag>456789123</OtherTag>
</Document>
$ perl demo.pl input.txt input.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document>
  <Tag>987654321</Tag>
  <Tag>876543219</Tag>
  <Tag>765432198</Tag>
  <OtherTag>456789123</OtherTag>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- replacement strings are to be processed as whole 'words' (ie, they are not to be replaced if they show up as a substring of a larger string of text
- replacements are only to be processed between `<Tag>` and `</Tag>` delimiters
- `<Tag>` and the matching `</Tag>` are always on the same line (ie, no linebreaks between the two delimiters)

Sample data:

```
$ cat tags.xml
...
<Tag>123456789</Tag>
<Don't change me>123456789</Tag>
<Tag>XX_123456789_YY</Tag>
...

$ cat replacements
123456789    987654321
234567891    876543219
345678912    765432198
456789123    654321987
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { rep[$1]=$2; next}
        { for (old in rep)
              gsub("Tag>" old "<","Tag>" rep[old] "<")
        }
1
' replacements tags.xml
```

This generates:

```
...
<Tag>987654321</Tag>
<Don't change me>123456789</Tag>
<Tag>XX_123456789_YY</Tag>
...
```